Containerised Spring Boot APP fails to connect to Local MySQL
I am trying to run a Spring Boot App in docker container and connect to the local mysql server. I have mostly tried all solution I have found. Following are the related files.
Dockerfile
# Dockerfile

# Use an official OpenJDK 17 runtime as a parent image
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim

# Add Maintainer Info
LABEL maintainer="Name"

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /demoapp

# Install mysql client
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y default-mysql-client

# Copy the application JAR file into the container at /app
COPY target/demoapp.jar /demoapp/

# Copy the startup script into the container
COPY start.sh /demoapp/
RUN chmod +x /demoapp/start.sh

# Expose the port the app runs on
EXPOSE 9092

# Specify the command to run on container start
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/demoapp/start.sh"]

docker-compose.yml
version: '3.1'
services:
 demoapp:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "9092:9092"
  networks:
    - da-network
networks:
  da-network:

application.yml
spring:
   datasource:
      url: jdbc:mysql://host.docker.internal:3306/demoapp
      username: daadmin
      password: Password123

start.sh
#!/bin/bash

# MySQL server details
MYSQL_HOST="host.docker.internal"
MYSQL_PORT="3306"
MYSQL_USER="daadmin"
MYSQL_PASS="Password123"

# Try to ping the MySQL server
if mysqladmin ping -h"$MYSQL_HOST" -P"$MYSQL_PORT" -u"$MYSQL_USER" -p"$MYSQL_PASS" --silent; then
    echo "Successfully connected to MySQL server."
else
    echo "Unable to connect to MySQL server."
    exit 1
fi

# Start the application
java -jar demoapp.jar

Through start.sh bash script I can see it can ping using mysqladmin. But the app does not connect to mysql server. I have updated the my.cnf to set the following

bind-address = 0.0.0.0

Following is the error log:
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

My local machine is a MacBook with M1 Max processor.
